# How can I compare two arrays contains same items or not in groovy?

Tags: arrays, groovy, compare

How can I compare two arrays contains same items or not?

```
def a = [1, 3, 2]
def b = [2, 1, 3]
def c = [2, 4, 3, 1]
```

a & b are contains same items, but a & c not.

Comment: They are lists, not arrays... Which do you mean?

Comment: @nikli in the code above they are not arrays, they're lists

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try converting them into Sets and then comparing them, as the equality in Sets is defined as having the same elements regardless of the order.

```
assert a as Set == b as Set
assert a as Set != c as Set
```

Comment: That works as long as the list elements are not duplicated.  For lists that can have duplicates, this method won't detect if they have the same number of each individual element. (I don't get the impression this is something the OP cares about so your answer is still valid, just an FYI for others that find this answer).

Answer (score 10):

Simply sorting the results and comparing is an easy way, if your lists are not too large:

```
def a = [1, 3, 2]
def b = [2, 1, 3]
def c = [2, 4, 3, 1]

def haveSameContent(a1, a2) {
    a1.sort(false) == a2.sort(false)
}

assert haveSameContent(a, b) == true
assert haveSameContent(a, c) == false
```

The `false` passed to `sort` is to prevent in-place reordering.  If it's OK to change the order of the lists, you can remove it and possibly gain a little bit of performance.

Comment: There is no point in comparing a boolean value with `true` or `false`. I think `assert haveSameContent(a, b)` and `assert !haveSameContent(a, c)` reads better.

Comment: That's really a matter of opinion.  I think it makes it clearer with the `== false` that you expect a false output.  It's rather easy to miss a single exclamation mark when skimming code.  (Also, don't forget, due to Groovy truth, `!0` or `![]` returns `true`, but `assert [] == false` will fail.)